# How can I fix the Bash terminal crashing issue in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried to use the bash terminal on vs-code but it keeps crashing with this message:

The terminal process "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe '--login', '-i'" terminated with exit code: 1.

and also:

Skipping command-line '"C:\Program Files\Git\bin..\usr\bin\bash.exe"'
('C:\Program Files\Git\bin..\usr\bin\bash.exe' not found)
Need a valid command-line; Edit the string resources accordingly

I don't know how to fix this problem or what to do.

I have already looked elsewhere on the internet and I was not able to find a way to fix it as in the end it still crashed.

Comment: the bash shell is crashing? Or VS Code is crashing? If it's the former, check the output panel's various channels to see if there's any more info there.

Comment: could you maybe clarify about the output panel's channels.

Comment: explanation video by Matt Bernier: https://youtu.be/ls6clvYr4Ow